# Does code require the gas line to be replaced when replacing a furnace?

Tags: hvac, gas, code-compliance

I replaced my 45 year old (still working) original furnace with an American Standard furnace about 5 1/2 years ago. Now I have a gas leak; the Nicor technician sealed a connection in the gas pipe connected to the furnace. He noticed the original gas line was being used & was crooked & could not thread properly, causing the gas leak.

Should old gas lines be replaced w/new installation? Is that "code"?

Comment: It depends on the type of pipe, and the fittings.  Brass fittings should not be reused, steel fittings may be able to be reused (depending on their condition). If you read the warning label on [flexible supply lines](http://www.lowes.com/pd_14038-72906-CSSD44E-48+P_4294935907__?productId=3130663), it tells you not to reuse it.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.  Usually in these situations the existing infrastructure must be brought up to current code.   A licensed installer would not install the furnace without insuring that the supply and the exhaust were up to current standards.